# What's a 3D doing in this HTML?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm trying to duplicate a mailer I got into my gmail by taking a look at its code. I see a lot of this in multiple source viewers:

```
 <td style=3D"border-bottom: 1px dotted rgb(153,157, 147); border-top: 1px solid rgb(28, 140, 78);" width=3D"90">=A0</td>
 <td style=3D"border-bottom: 1px dotted rgb(153,157, 147); border-top: 1px solid rgb(28, 140, 78);" align=3D"right" width=3D"110">
```

Is 3D some sort of mail rendering thing I don't know about?

Comment: PHP has a method for converting a quoted-printable string to an 8 bit string
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php

Answer (score 483, accepted):

It's an email encoding system called "[quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable)", which allows non-ASCII characters to be represented as ASCII for email transportation.

In quoted-printable, any non-standard email octets are represented as an `=` sign followed by two hex digits representing the octet's value. Of course, to represent a plain `=` in email, it needs to be represented using quoted-printable encoding too: 3D are the hex digits corresponding to `=`'s ASCII value (61).

Comment: Yup. You should see `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable` in the headers if QP is used.

Comment: Interesting! Do I need to incorporate that into my email template, or will it be ok without it?

Comment: @melee: Don't write in QP by hand (i.e., your template should use `=`, not `=3D`). :-) If your email software needs to use QP, it'll convert automatically.

Comment: Saving you the inevitable search for a decoder: http://www.motobit.com/util/quoted-printable-decoder.asp

Comment: In my case it was the use of one character in the email message that caused it to change `Content-Transfer-Encoding`. Replacing — with - solved it.

Comment: @Stephen, In the past there are no hex viewers, only text viewers.

Comment: To decode, one can use [the Python standard library's `quopri.decodestring(s)`](https://docs.python.org/library/quopri.html)

Comment: This is why if you send an email in a non-Latin language such as Japanese, it will be encoded that way too! For example sending `こんにちは` results in `=
=E3=81=93=E3=82=93=E3=81=AB=E3=81=A1=E3=81=AF` at the destination, which is quoted-printable encoding on top of UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: If you are using PHP you can use quoted_printable_decode($htmlmsg) to remove the =xx and replace it with the right stuff.

Comment: This one works well too: https://www.webatic.com/quoted-printable-convertor

Answer (score -5):

Folks from Google using Laravel, you can stop the `Mail` facade from adding all this weird `3D` stuff by setting your encoder to raw:

```
$message->setEncoder(new Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder_RawContentEncoder);
```

Comment: An explanation?

Comment: Edit your answer adding the explanation you wrote in the comment, and I will upvote it.

Comment: This will force laravel to send the mail in 8bit encoding instead of the base64 required for "quoted-printable", so it won't encode "quoted-printable", so the 3D characters will not be added. The problem here isn't how it's send, but how the receiver interprets the mail. Most likely due to missing headers in the e-mail.