# gmail splits my html code

Tags: php, html, email, split, gmail

I'm sending this HTML with the PHP `mail()` function:

```
    <div>hello<div><br></div><div>dsfs</div><div><b style="background-color:rgb(255,0,0)">dfs</b></div><div><b style="background-color:rgb(255,0,0)">df</b></div><div><b style="background-color:rgb(255,0,0)">sdf</b></div><div>sdf</div>
<div>sdfff</div></div>
```

It's a really simple HTML email, but Gmail shows this:

```
hello
dfs
df
<= div style=3D"color:rgb(34,34,34);font-family:arial,sans-serif;font-size:13p= x;background-color:rgb(255,255,255)"> sdf
sdf
sdfff
```

Why is Gmail truncating my HTML and how can I fix it?

i'm directly catching the html code what was sent from gmail file_get_contents("php://stdin"); and processing this to extract the html code (i only remove the headers), therefore the html is perfectly correct and i don't must edit this. then, why if gmail send the html to another gmail this looks good but else i send the html this is a html disaster?

**seriously, the html is perfectly according gmail**

Comment: You will never be happy with the results of your HTML output in any email client. They are designed to eliminate any possibly malicious code. I recommend using an email testing platform such as *litmus* or *email on acid*.

Comment: Also, are you using the `email()` function or the `mail()` function?

Comment: If you are using `<div>`s you have to render your message in some way before including in the email body, other wise you will have to use normal text with only `<br/>`, `<p>` and that sort of tags on.
Probably you can try to use a `<table>` in your email

Comment: Perhaps off topic, but you really need to choose a better naming convention for your filler text. For example, it would be far easier to understand what's going on with the basic Line 1, Line 2... Line 6; not the dsfs dsf sdfs used, which really strains the mind to follow.

Comment: I've seen this `style=3D"` thing before but I can't remember where... Check this out maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016067/whats-a-3d-doing-in-this-html

Answer (score 1):

This is what your code should look like with proper formatting. I have moved your inline styles to the `<div>` since I'm not 100% certain how valid it is within a `<b>` tag.

```
<div>hello 
    <div><br /></div>
    <div>dsfs</div>
    <div style="background-color:rgb(255,0,0)"><b>dfs</b></div>
    <div style="background-color:rgb(255,0,0)"><b>df</b></div>
    <div style="background-color:rgb(255,0,0)"><b>sdf</b></div>
    <div>sdf</div>
    <div>sdfff</div>
</div>
```

Nothing is being truncated. `<div>` tags always display below one another unless the `float` or `display:inline` styles are set.

Comment: this is a valid html, if i send formated mail from gmail to my postfix server, the html is shown exactly how i published here.

Comment: On second look, you're right. I misread your tags. Try my updated code and see if it helps.

Comment: Why would `background` or `style` not be valid on a `b` tag?

Comment: @Wesley Not sure, but email clients have a habit of doing some really wacky things.

Comment: i'm directly catching the html code what was sent from gmail file_get_contents("php://stdin"); and processing this to extract the html code (i only remove the headers), therefore the html is perfectly correct and i don't must edit this.
then, why if gmail send the html to another gmail this looks good but else i send the html this is a html disaster?

Comment: Your problem likely lies in `get_file_contents()`. I cannot know for sure what the problem is, but if forwarding the email from one gmail account to another creates no problems, it has to be some sort of processing that is done within `get_file_contents()`.

Comment: What does a source-code inspection show you when viewing the email through the client? (F12 in Chrome, or you can right-click and select *inspect element*)

Comment: the gmail splits the html like lines
<a href="123456789123456789123456789">hi</a>
is splited as <a href="1234567891234 56789123456789">hi</a>
wtf gmail splits the html?

Comment: Your problem has **nothing** to do with gmail. It lies in `get_file_contents()`. Find out why it would convert characters and you'll find your solution.