# Laravel 4 email template styling

Tags: css, email, laravel-4, laravel-blade, email-templates

I'm trying to give a style to my email template using bootstrap but every time what laravel is doing is, it parses the template and adds a '**3D**' where ever there is '**=**' in the template, which results in `style=3D"table"` instead of `style="table"`, here is a snippet of the mail source code

```
<div class=3D"well">
   <table class=3D"table table-bordered table-striped" id=3D'table'>
      <thead>
         <th>Group Name</th>
         <th>Kpi Name</th>
         <th>User Name</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

here is my code for template

```
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        {{ HTML::style('app\\client\\css\\bootstrap.css') }}
        {{ HTML::script('app\\javascripts\\js\\jquery-1.8.3.min.js') }}
        {{ HTML::script('app\\client\\js\\bootstrap.min.js') }}
        <style>
            #table {
                border: 2px solid #ccc;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="well">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id='table'>
                <thead>
                <th>Group Name</th>
                <th>Kpi Name</th>
                <th>User Name</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach ($groups as $group)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $group['name'] }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <ul>
                                @if (array_key_exists('kpis', $group))    
                                @foreach ($group['kpis'] as $kpi)                            
                                <li>{{ Kpi::find($kpi['kpi'])->title }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                                @endif
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <ul>
                                @if (array_key_exists('users', $group))
                                @foreach ($group['users'] as $user)
                                <li>{{ User::find($user['user'])->fName.' '.User::find($user['user'])->lName }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                                @endif
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <br>
            <br>
            Regards,<br>
            <strong>Yogesh Joshi</strong><br>
            Group Leader
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

is there something I'm missing or there is some problem in **laravel or mail-server** (**gmail or hotmail**), and yeah I've cross checked the script and style files, they do exists in public folder.

please help or provide any alternate method for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the =3D items, see this post: [What's a 3D doing in this HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016067/whats-a-3d-doing-in-this-html)

And I see that you are trying to load javascript in your email, that's not a good idea. see: [Is JavaScript supported in an email message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054315/is-javascript-supported-in-an-email-message)

And I am not sure about loading a stylesheet into a html email, so I will leave that one open.

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap in emails sounds a little bit overkill, but there's old project called [Bootstrap Template for HTML Email](https://github.com/advancedrei/BootstrapForEmail). Not sure if this helps.

Also this question seems to be partially about the same subject as SO question "[Has anyone gotten HTML emails working with Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732580/has-anyone-gotten-html-emails-working-with-twitter-bootstrap/10205670)"

Probably easier to use [HTML Email Boilerplate](http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/) with just copied mini style sheet from your actual project.

Or if you're lazy, use the Mailchimp wysiwyg -editor and export it out of MC. They have really nice wysiwyg-editor and responsive templates. I've been using it and it saves some time and effort.