# Getting `=` in email html

Tags: html, asp.net

below is the html that i send from asp.net application

```
 <HTML>

<BODY>
    <img src='http://10.1.1.42:8090/EmailLogo/8aaebe52-3758-485f-8c52-7782707a4c66.jpg' />
    <br/>
    <div style='font-family:Arial, Tahoma; font-size:13px; line-height:18px; color:#000; background:#edfcff; padding:15px; border:1px solid #b6dee8;'>
        <div style='font-size:18px; color:#2c8cbe; margin-bottom:15px;'>HH,</div>
        <div>Test 1</div>
    </div>
    <div style='color: rgb(104, 104, 104); font-size: 12px; font-family: lucida grande, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; border: medium none; padding: 10px;'>
        <br />IMPORTANT NOTICE:This email message and any attachments are intended only for the use of the addressee named above. If you are not the intended recipient, any dissemination, distribution or copying is strictly prohibited. If you received this
        message in error, please immediately notify the sender by replying to this email message or by telephone. Thank you.</div>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

But the rendered html in the email is as below:

```
<HTML>

<BODY>
    <img src=3D 'http://10.1.1.42:8099/EmailLogo/8aaebe52-=
3758-485f-8c52-7782707a4c66.jpg' />
    <br/>
    <div style=3D 'font-family=
:Arial, Tahoma; font-size:13px; line-height:18px; color:#000; bac=
kground:#edfcff; padding:15px; border:1px solid #b6dee8;'>
        <div st=y le=3D 'font-size:18px; color:#2c8cbe; margin-bottom:15px;'>HH,</d=i v>
            <div>Test 1</div>
        </div>
        <div style=3D 'color: rgb(104, 104, 104)=
; font-size: 12px; font-family: lucida grande, Tahoma, Verdana, A=
rial, sans-serif; border: medium none; padding: 10px;'>
            <br />IMPO= RTANT NOTICE:This email message and any attachments are intended = only for the use of the addressee named above. If you are not the= intended recipient, any dissemination, distribution or copying i= s strictly prohibited. If you received
            this message in error, ple= ase immediately notify the sender by replying to this email messa= ge or by telephone. Thank you.</div>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

As you can notice `=` has cropped up at many places.Anyone known why??

Comment: Post your code which you have used for sending mail..!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016067/whats-a-3d-doing-in-this-html

Answer (score 1):

Please change encoding to UTF-8