# Email markup-Gmail modifying the <script> tag to add extra string "3D"

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, email, google-schemas

I am using Ruby on Rails to generate the email. As mentioned in the [Email markup docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/restaurant-reservation), i modified my (*.html.haml) templates to include the schema for *Email markup*. Below code is from my mailer template:

```
%script{ type: "application/ld+json" }
  {
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "FoodEstablishmentReservation",
  "reservationNumber" : "#{reservation.id}",
  ...
  }
```

I also modified the sender and receiver of the email to the same email id as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/testing-your-schema) for testing the schema in development mode.

When i receive the email in my Gmail inbox, and i don't see anything different from before. When i check the *Original Message* of the email, it shows:

```
Return-Path: <breezebhoewal@gmail.com>
...
Date: Wed, 21 Dec 2016 13:14:45 +0530
From: breezebhoewal@gmail.com
To: breezebhoewal@gmail.com
...
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="--==_mimepart_585a32ecf2d94_143673fd10d24128893014"; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

----==_mimepart_585a32ecf2d94_143673fd10d24128893014
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
...
<script type=3D'application/ld+json'>
  {
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "FoodEstablishmentReservation",
  "reservationNumber" : "<reservation-id>",
  ...
  }
</script>
...
```

Now, if i validate this `<script>` tag content in the [Email markup tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/), it says "no structured data is present", but as soon as i remove "3D" from `<script>` tag and make it `<script type='application/ld+json'>`, it extracts the structured data correctly for all the fields.

So, i am unable to figure out why this extra string "3D" is being added to the HTML? Is it because of Haml? or Gmail does it? AND is there anything i can fix to test this Email markup in development environment. Let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: It is an email encoding system, which allows non-ASCII characters to be represented as ASCII for email transportation. This encoding is called "quoted-printable", that is why there is a 3D value in your email. If you will check this related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4016098/5995040), which discussed some ways to avoid this like changing it to "Content-Transfer-Encoding". Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you find how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem. It turns out I had a few misunderstandings which I will help clarify:

1) As pointed out above, the "Original Message" you saw in gmail was encoded as quoted-printable. You first have to decode the message, e.g. using  [Quoted Printable Converter](http://www.webatic.com/run/convert/qp.php), and the decoded message does not contain any 3Ds. The decoded message will then validate correctly (presumeably) using the Email Markup tester you referenced.

2) I arrived at this thread because I was debugging my integration using email markup. The markup wasn't showing in test emails and I thought I was implementing it incorrectly. I discovered my email schema integration must be [whitelisted](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google) by Google to use these features.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You donʼt need to register with Google to send test emails from yourself to yourself on the same account, which OP was doing.

From the docs: “All schemas you send to yourself (from x@gmail.com to x@gmail.com) will be displayed in Google products. So go ahead and try it out now!”

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding this meta tag in header

```
 <meta charset="charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
```