# Event description in JSON-LD does not appear to be interpreted in Gmail

Tags: email, google-schemas

I am trying to send emails through Amazon SES containing JSON-LD markup describing events. It seems the JSON-LD markup is not correctly interpreted by GMail. When I send the following email:

```
Delivered-To: xxxx
Received: by 10.12.172.196 with SMTP id n4csp579890qvc;
        Thu, 5 Jan 2017 13:49:46 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.99.133.72 with SMTP id u69mr115789915pgd.171.1483652986711;
        Thu, 05 Jan 2017 13:49:46 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <01010159709bf387-549c9c02-0d18-4dd6-b62d-1ddd02af1c6d-000000@us-west-2.amazonses.com>
Received: from a27-31.smtp-out.us-west-2.amazonses.com (a27-31.smtp-out.us-west-2.amazonses.com. [54.240.27.31])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id 129si77096101pgi.256.2017.01.05.13.49.46
        (version=TLS1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA bits=128/128);
        Thu, 05 Jan 2017 13:49:46 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of 01010159709bf387-549c9c02-0d18-4dd6-b62d-1ddd02af1c6d-000000@us-west-2.amazonses.com designates 54.240.27.31 as permitted sender) client-ip=54.240.27.31;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@amazonses.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of 01010159709bf387-549c9c02-0d18-4dd6-b62d-1ddd02af1c6d-000000@us-west-2.amazonses.com designates 54.240.27.31 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=01010159709bf387-549c9c02-0d18-4dd6-b62d-1ddd02af1c6d-000000@us-west-2.amazonses.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/simple; s=gdwg2y3kokkkj5a55z2ilkup5wp5hhxx; d=amazonses.com; t=1483652985; h=From:To:Cc:Subject:MIME-Version:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Message-ID:Date:Feedback-ID; bh=VpX7AK5j+C7MDvAczy7KZk47RwxY9jPmDibnhAfONUk=; b=lIR9RNp1du+D1sbpncmFd+dvA5UIJe1vOGd16t5S/ps7pkDiQxupjNfnbSjyfrNj SD84YMW04JXO/ZDTEqqmbEng3FUQ72WPepneiYS8cdUUxB4B607EbAPuzEVmayPZiJk 7/p6gtvADVrzM3kd2tZl2kdCWUzdXXs+MeMUXGEc=
From: zzzz
To: xxx
Subject: Visit Booking
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Message-ID: <01010159709bf387-549c9c02-0d18-4dd6-b62d-1ddd02af1c6d-000000@us-west-2.amazonses.com>
Date: Thu, 5 Jan 2017 21:49:45 +0000
X-SES-Outgoing: 2017.01.05-54.240.27.31
Feedback-ID: 1.us-west-2.6sejDnKm/LBlMdOhtkRGcGMMomxZHN6VusoM3xuprsk=:AmazonSES

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang=3D"en"><head><title>Book a visit</title><meta =
http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dutf-8"></head><=
body><script type=3D"application/ld+json">{"reservationStatus":"http://sche=
ma.org/Pending","@context":"http://schema.org","underName":{"name":"Arnaud"=
,"@type":"Person"},"@type":"EventReservation","reservationFor":{"location":=
{"address":{"streetAddress":"Some Quay","postalCode":"123456","address=
Country":"Singapore","addressLocality":"Singapore","@type":"PostalAddress"}=
,"name":"The Quay","@type":"Place"},"endDate":"2016-12-12T14:3=
0:00+00:00","startDate":"2016-12-12T14:00:00+00:00","name":"Visit The =
Quay","@type":"Event"},"reservationNumber":"12345"}</script><p>Dear=
 Arnaud</p><p>Your request to book a visit with has been take=
n into account</p></body></ht=
ml>
```

I would expect an event to appear in my calendar as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation). I copy/pasted the HTML content in [Email markup tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/) and only got warnings, while the embedded data was interpreted correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the schema is correct but one needs to [register with Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google) for schemas to interpreted by Gmail client. Which makes sense...

Comment: Yes, the schema you generated should work when you register with Google. For development, you can only test it on the tool they provide to validate the schema. I had a similar issue while working on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41258309/email-markup-gmail-modifying-the-script-tag-to-add-extra-string-3d