# Google email markup not showing

Tags: email, google-schemas

I'm trying to make a simple view action using Email markup from Google inside my emails (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action#view_action)

I use this `ld+json` inside my email template

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "ViewAction",
    "target": http://google.com",
    "url": "http://google.com",
    "name": See ticket"
  }
}
</script>
```

I used Google email markup tester to valid this code.

I use registred emails (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google)

But I still can show the emails markup on Gmail.

Did I miss something ?

Do you have any clues ?

Thanks

Comment: I guess the markup is valid. Just make sure that you registered with Google before you send emails to other users properly. Try to double check it with the [doc](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google). Be noted that Emails must be [authenticated via DKIM or SPF](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/180707?hl=en#). If you're using Google SMTP relay, you have to use an SPF record looking like [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/178723?hl=en):  `v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all`.

Comment: See if this resembles your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41258309/email-markup-gmail-modifying-the-script-tag-to-add-extra-string-3d