# Google Markup not seen in e-mail

Tags: google-schemas

I test send markups with Google scripts and works find,
if send the same template via Google SMTP from my Gmail account to my Gmail account the `ld+json` don't see.

My template is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prenotazine TiPrenota</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "EventReservation",
      "reservationNumber": "5aa46b79-140d-491e-a1db-568ec1c423bd",
      "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
      "underName": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Savio Capannini"
      },
      "reservationFor": {
        "@type": "Event",
        "name": "SAN MARINO ADVENTURES SRL - COE 21269",
        "startDate": "2017-03-27T12:30:00",
        "location": {
          "@type": "Place",
          "name": "SAN MARINO ADVENTURES SRL - COE 21269",
          "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress": "San Marino Adventure Parco Montecerreto, San Marino (RSM)"
          },
          "geo": {
            "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
            "latitude": "44,490501",
            "longitude": "12,281881"
          }
        },
        "performer":"Reservation"
      },
      "modifyReservationUrl": "https://www.mysite.it/?token=5aa46b79-140d-491e-a1db-568ec1c423bd"
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Testo emeil
</body>
</html>
```

Do I need a G Suite account to try this?
Why the markup is not seen?
Where is the problem?

Pleas help!
Thks.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41564946/google-email-markup-not-showing). Make sure that you [registered with Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google) before you send emails to other users properly. Also, be noted that Emails must be [authenticated via DKIM or SPF](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/180707?hl=en#). If you're using Google SMTP relay, you have to use an SPF record looking like [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/178723?hl=en): `v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all`.

Here's another thread which might help: [Gmail Email Markup not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216823/gmail-email-markup-not-working)