# Email action google-schema markup doesn't work

Tags: email, schema.org, google-schemas

I'm sending markups copied from [google developers reference](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/getting-started) (also [from here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action)). They don't work at all, even when I [email to myself](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google#email_sender_quality_guidelines).

I also tested [sending html email with google doc](https://www.labnol.org/internet/send-html-email/19672/)

Comment: What is not working?What does the error logs say? Which part did you stumble?

Comment: @noogui  Sorry if I was not descriptive enough.
by "doesn't work" I mean gmail applications don't show any special button like what they do for example for Github or google calendar emails. I can add the raw message if it may help. I don't know which "log" you were mentioning.

Comment: Please go through this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41258309/email-markup-gmail-modifying-the-script-tag-to-add-extra-string-3d. May be it is the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Alireza Mirian It sounds like you're copying the JSON and pasting it into your email message in the Gmail UI.

Try using this [tool](https://gmail-actions.appspot.com)  with your Gmail account.

You can also try using [App Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) and follow along with this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, no I'm not using Gmail UI as it doesn't support html source editing.

Comment: Thank you anyways. I will try the links you provided.

Comment: No problem. Try the first link, as it's a faster way to test Gmail actions.