# Send base64 image using nodemailer

Tags: node.js, base64, nodemailer

Here is how I'm try to send html email with base64 image using nodemailer.

```
html: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />`,
```

but instead of original html I receive email with following:

```
<img src=3D"data:image/png;base64,=
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBK=
E0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=3D=3D" />
```

where/what adds these "3D" and how to send right base64 image?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically `=` is replaced with `=3D` in your case. This is happening because of the email encoding system called [quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable), which allows `non-ASCII` characters to be represented as `ASCII` characters for `email transportation.`

In quoted-printable, any non-standard email octets are represented as an = sign followed by two hex digits representing the octet's value. 3D is hex (quoted-printable) representation of ASCII =.

Set `Content-Transfer-Encoding : quoted-printable` in the headers.

See [What's a 3D doing in this HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016067/whats-a-3d-doing-in-this-html) for more information.

Comment: I have add
      `headers: {
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'quoted-printable',
      },`
to message options, but this doesn't help, I don't see image (in web-interface of my email provider).

Comment: I see my image only when I forward message and mail provider change Content-Transfer-Encoding from quoted-printable to 8-bit

Comment: What happens if you change the content-transfer-encoding to 8 bit yourself??

Comment: It change to base64, encode all message to base64 and image still not visible