# What is type of this string and how to handle it?

Tags: c#, html, email, text, eml

This a part of Body in eml file (email body)

```
<div style=3D"direction:rtl;text-align:right;">
    <b> =D8=B3=D8=B1=D9=88=DB=8C=D8=B3 =D8=A7=D8=B4=D8=AA=D8=B1=D8=A7=DA=A9=
 =D9=88=DB=8C=D8=AF=DB=8C=D9=88 - =D8=A2=D9=BE=D8=A7=D8=B1=D8=A7=D8=AA =D8=
=AF=D8=A7=D8=AA =DA=A9=D8=A7=D9=85
    </b>

    =DA=A9=D8=A7=D8=B1=D8=A8=D8=B1 =DA=AF=D8=B1=D8=A7=D9=85=DB=8C=D8=9B =D8=
=A8=D8=A7 =D8=B3=D9=84=D8=A7=D9=85
    <br>
```

How to Convert this string to Readable Text ?

Comment: Please try the following link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016067/whats-a-3d-doing-in-this-html

Comment: Seems to be an arabic text: https://www.webatic.com/quoted-printable-convertor

Comment: @HansKesting: The duplicate link answers only the first part of the question. For the second part there are some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226554/c-class-for-decoding-quoted-printable-encoding) but actually none of them works for special encodings. As I cannot answer the question anymore I created a fiddle with the working answer: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Fy8Bs

Comment: ThanX everyone !