# = and 3D Character in html | non-ASCII characters | quoted-printable | Django email templates

Tags: django, python-3.x, basic-authentication

Django 2, Python 3.

On sending user signup emails using Django default authentication. The sent email contains corrupted html.

> contains **3D** with each attribute's equal sign.

**`style=3D"margin:`**

> contains **=** with each starting new line.

**`padd=`**
**`ing-top:20px;`**

**Sample Code:**

```
<div style="padding: 40px; background: #fff;">
    <table style="width: 100%;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #f6f6f6;">
                    <h1 style="font-size:14px; font-family:arial; margin:0px; font-weight:bold;">{% trans 'Greetings!,' %}</h1>
                    <p style="margin-top:0px; color:#bbbbbb;">{% trans 'Here are your account activation instructions.' %}</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:10px 0 30px 0;">
                    <p>{% trans 'Thank you for joining us.' %}</p>
                    <p>{% trans 'To activate your profile, please follow this link:' %}</p>
                    <center>
                        <a href="{{ uri }}" style="display: inline-block; padding: 11px 30px; margin: 20px 0px 30px; font-size: 15px; color: #fff; background: #4fc3f7; border-radius: 60px; text-decoration:none;">{% trans 'Activate Profile' %}</a>
                    </center>
                    <b>- {% trans 'Thanks (project team)' %}</b> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="border-top:1px solid #f6f6f6; padding-top:20px; color:#777">{% trans 'If the button above does not work, try copying and pasting the URL into your browser. If you continue to have problems, please feel free to contact us at info@project.com' %}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Generated HTML template:**

```
<div style=3D"padding: 40px; background: #fff;">
    <table style=3D"width: 100%;" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=
    =3D"0" border=3D"0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style=3D"border-bottom:1px solid #f6f6f6;">
                <h1 style=3D"font-size:14px; font-family:ar=
                ial; margin:0px; font-weight:bold;">Greetings!,</h1>
                <p style=3D"margin-top:0px; color:#bbbbbb;"=
                >Here are your account activation instructions.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style=3D"padding:10px 0 30px 0;">
                <p>Thank you for joining us.</p>
                <p>To activate your profile, please follow =
                this link:</p>
                <center>
                    <a href=3D"http://localhost:8000/accoun=
                    ts/activate/uyi90WsYyvLKmn4wwwqq/" style=3D"display: inline-block; padding:=
                    11px 30px; margin: 20px 0px 30px; font-size: 15px; color: #fff; background=
                    : #4fc3f7; border-radius: 60px; text-decoration:none;">Activate Profile</a>
                </center>
                <b>- Thanks (project team)</b> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style=3D"border-top:1px solid #f6f6f6; padd=
                ing-top:20px; color:#777">If the button above does not work, try copying an=
                d pasting the URL into your browser. If you continue to have problems, plea=
            se feel free to contact us at info@project.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**Please help resolve/identify the issue.**

Comment: Have you taken a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016067/whats-a-3d-doing-in-this-html

Comment: please explain it in better way as answer.

Comment: Is this the HTML that Django generates directly or is it the HTML you are viewing in an email client?

Comment: it is html generated by django directly.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to generate the email

Comment: please view question. I posted code.

Comment: And the python code that you run to generate it...

Comment: I am using django default user authentication, so the views and models are in built django package. I just customized html template.

Comment: only email templates rendered corrupt. rest of the app pages works fine

Comment: This is not corrupt html. This is how raw emails actually look like because it is being transformed into Quoted-Printable encoding, as opposed to ASCII or UTF-8 encoding. So, `=` is in ASCII. But in QP, it get's converted to `=3D`. Both actually represent the same character but in two different encoding formats. If you view this email in an email client, the page should display as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue while running tests and wanted to share the issue and how to deal with it

During tests Django sets the email backend to locmem and we use the `django.core.mail.outbox` which returns an array with the sent emails to test their content

So, considering one sent email as the first element of such array:

```py
from django.core import mail
sent_email = mail.outbox[0]
```

Checking the content and getting the clear HTML:

```py
sent_email.alternatives[0][0]
```

Getting the Quoted-Printable encoding (with the =3D):

```py
sent_email.message().get_payload()[1].get_payload()
```