# How to remove =20 etc from Gmail "Show Original"

Tags: html, email, gmail, html-email

I'm trying to get the HTML from an email in my Gmail inbox
I've clicked on "View Original". However the HTML there has lots of extra little strings like "=20" in it, which then causes problems with rendering it when I paste it elsewhere. Is there an easy way to remove all of these?

E.g. here's the start of the email

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=3D"en">
<head>

=09
=09
=09

   =20
=09<meta charset=3D"utf-8">
=09<meta http-equiv=3D"X-UA-Compatible" content=3D"IE=3Dedge">
=09<meta name=3D"viewport" content=3D"width=3Ddevice-width, initial-scale=
=3D1">
=09<META NAME=3D"ROBOTS" CONTENT=3D"NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
=09<title>Your order details</title>
```

Comment: this is an ongoing issue?

Comment: @Mech yes, it happens with every email

Comment: oh this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016067/whats-a-3d-doing-in-this-html and in the comments, here is a decoder: https://www.motobit.com/util/quoted-printable-decoder.asp